# $T^2$ is measure preserving but $T$ is not measure preserving

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I have had trouble with this exercise. Can anyone help?

Give an example of a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and a measurable mapping
$T : \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ such that $T^2$ is measure preserving but $T$ is not measure preserving.

There is a hint that I should consider a space $\Omega$ containing only two points.

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega=\{a,b\}$ with $\mathbb P(\{a\})=1/3, \mathbb P(\{b\})=2/3$ and $T(a)=b$, $T(b)=a$. Then $T^2(a)=a$, $T^2(b)=b$ and this is measure-preserving transformation since it is identity.

But $T$ is not measure preserving: say, for $A=\{a\}$, $\mathbb P(TA)\neq \mathbb P(A)$.

Comment: Dear NCh. Thanks for the answer. From my understanding T is measure preserving precisely when $P(T^{-1}(F))=P(F)$ for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$. Not $P(T(F))=P(F)$ for all $F \in \mathcal{F}$. Thus I would say your answer is wrong. I have thought about it myself. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MathGunne $T$ and $T^2$ are both bijective so $P(T^{-1}(F))=P(F)$ is equivalent to $P(T(F))=P(F)$ here.

Comment: Ah I see.... Thx